# Remove two items from separate arrays in the same position

Tags: jquery

I've got two separate arrays which look like this

```
12-Jan-12 (remove), 14-Mar-12 (remove)
£139, £187
```

When someone click the remove button in array I need it to remove the the one from the second array in the same position

So if i clicked remove on the `12-Jan-12` then i want it to remove `£139` from the second array

Here's some code I have already to remove one from the first array

```
$('.delete-date').live('click', function() {

    $(this).closest('.myDate').remove();

});
```

Here's my HTML

```
<span class="dates">
    <span class="myDate">
        12-jan-12
        <span class="delete-date" title="remove this tag" />
    </span>,
    <span class="myDate">
        14-mar-12
        <span class="delete-date" title="remove this tag" />
    </span>,
</span>

<span class="costs">
    <span class="myCost">
        £139
    </span>,
    <span class="myCost">
        £187
    </span>,
</span>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't store this in an actual array correct? Just the HTML representation right?

Comment: @JohnP Yes that's correct I use the HTML representation in the Asp.Net code behind and use it as an array there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery you can get the index of an sibling with the `.index()` method and use the `.eq()`  method to select an element based on it's index. So:

```
var d = $(this).closest('.myDate');
var index = d.index();

d.remove();

$(".costs .myCost").eq(index).remove();
```

NB: Instead of `.live()`, you should consider using `delegate()` (or `.on()` with jQuery 1.7), as it's much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks - works great, I've not come across `.index()` before also not looked into jQuery 1.7 still using 1.6 I believe. I'll have a look into `delegate()` and `on()` - Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index() method to get the index of the element and find the matching one in the second set.

```
$('.delete-date').live('click', function() {
    var pos = $(this).closest('.myDate').index();
    $(this).closest('.myDate').remove();
    $('.costs .myCost').eq(pos).remove();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to combine

```
.index()
```

and

```
.eq()
```

For example, in a click event handler

```
var dateIndex = $(".dates").index($(this));
prices.eq(dateIndex).hide();
```